# error sobre sintaxis cuando actualizo tablas en sql

Tags: sql

Hola es que tengo un problema y ya he intentado solucionarlo, y he visto algunos ejemplos pero a mi no me funcionan. Tengo que actualizar un campo A que depende del campo B que viene de otra tabla diferente, es decir, si el campo b cumple cierta condición, entonces, que lo de campo b pase a campo a o, simplemnte poner campo a como vacío.

```
**UPDATE php_usuarios
SET php_usuarios.email = ps.ciudad
FROM php_usuarios PU 
INNER JOIN php_servicios PS 
ON PU.id = PS.id_usuario
WHERE ciudad = 'cali';**
```

Me sale este error

```
 #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'FROM php_usuarios PU 
 INNER JOIN php_servicios PS 
 ON PU.id = PS.id_usuario
 W' en la linea 3
```

Sé que debe ser algo muy simple pero estoy confundido, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, tienes un error de sintaxis en la sentencia, no tienes que añadir la cláusula FROM, la tabla a actualizar ya está incluida en la consulta.

[MySql UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

La consulta con sintaxis correcta te quedaría:

```
UPDATE php_usuarios
INNER JOIN php_servicios ON php_usuarios.id = php_servicios.id_usuario
SET php_usuarios.email = php_servicios.ciudad
WHERE php_servicios.ciudad = 'cali';
```

Comment: He dado por sentado que se trata de MySql por el código de error, pero estaría bien que lo indicaras en la pregunta.

Comment: eso era, gracias